# Fragment Lifecycle and recent Apps Screen - Variable is null

Tags: android, null, fragment, android-lifecycle

I want to manipulate a Variable (Object) in my Fragment once the User returns to the App from the Homescreen. Inside the Fragment i hold a reference to it. Say like this:

```
Object a;
```

However, when i try to manipulate the Variable in one of the following Methods (wich i overwrite inside the Fragment): **onStart, onResume or onViewStateRestored** OR in one of the following in the Activity **onResume, onStart, onPostResume** the variable is always null and callls on the the Object (like a.doSomething()) fail.

The Use Case: User starts my App, presses Home Button and returns to the said App via "recent Apps Screen"

Any ideas how to solve this? 
Preferably not with a delayed Threading Solution like "overwrite onResume, make Runnable that starts after 2 seconds and does the stuff in there"

I already noticed this only occurs when the User is quick and the Fragment is still alive in the Background and does not need to be recreated from scratch so to say, because when the fragment goes through onCreateView i am handling it via the normal use case of a normal app start

thanks

Comment: try putting the variable in the activity class and calling it from the fragment with ((YourActivity)getActivity).yourVariable